# Python: Single Module Package Structure

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'd like to apply the [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) process to a package with only one module/`.py` file.

I'm new to Python so I'm probably misunderstanding something here (but coding for decades), but many packaging tutorials I've seen lead to names that must be accessed like `mypackage.mymodule.xyz`. The trivial examples they show are often of the form `samelongname.samelongname`. For single module projects, that seems overkill.

My main objective is to just have one level of scoping for users i.e. `modulename`.

[Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) suggests the structure:

```
packaging_tutorial/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── src/
│   └── example_package/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── example.py
└── tests/
```

I specifically like the idea of putting the `.py` file under `src` to clearly distinguish it.

For one module and no package, I was thinking that would be (excerpted):

```
packaging_tutorial/
├── src/
│   └── example.py
```

The configuration they offer is (excerpted):

```
[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

However, when I do `python3 -m build`, the `.py` file does not end up in the built dist.

Before finding the linked docs, I was keeping the `.py` in the package root (i.e. not under `src`) and using a setup.py instead of a setup.cfg like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    py_modules=['mpvsilence']
)
```

That worked, but when I tried to make it more like the docs:

- `py_modules` doesn't seem to work in a setup.cfg.
- `py_modules=['src/mpvsilence']` didn't seem to work in the setup.py

I'm really just flopping around here. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the __init__.py empty file to your src folder? I think find_namespace doesn't need it, but find does? I use the py_modules with pyproject.toml+setup.cfg when I have a single Python script that I need to package, like your `mpvsilence.py` (you omit the extension as in your example). So I think when you moved that to a package it didn't work. Cheers